# Marca dágua em fotos

Tags: php, laravel, processamento-de-imagens, image

Boas pessoa, estou fazendo meu TCC e agora estou implementando uma galeria de fotos, mas preciso que  essas fotos apresentem uma marca dágua que o usuário escolher previamente, estou utilizando o **nanoGallery2** pra mostrar a galeria/fotos, e como back estou usando o **Laravel**.
O problema que enfrento é:
Eu queria somente que na hora de mostrar as fotos tivesse a marca dágua, porque queria manter o arquivo original, mas tenho medo que o usuário desative o JS e consiga "pegar" a foto sem a marca, pelo PHP eu consigo inserir a marca dágua. Tentei utilizar a biblioteca Intervention\Image e mais umas 2, mas normalmente o Opacity demorava mais de 30 segundos por imagem. A única que consegui fazer funciona mais "rápido" foi a bliblioteca do claviska\SimpleImage, mas em  40 fotos, demorou quase 30 segundos, o que ainda é muito.

Enfim, não sei qual caminho pegar...

O que vocês me aconselham?

Agradeço

Comment: Que tal manter duas cópias? A original por histórico e a com marca d'Água para exibição?

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas o tempo que leva pra salvar também fica alto, a imagem já demora normalmente no upload, depois o back ainda vai inserir uma watermark, isso demora mais alguns segundos por imagem.. Eu estou utilziando o Dropzone para upload.. Então mais tempo.. fora o espaço que será em dobro.

Comment: Acho que isso é uma conflito de escolha, que terá que balancear. Você quer prevenir que tenha acesso à imagem original, portanto isso deve ser feito no PHP. Ou você demora uma vez 30 segundos (no upload) ou você demora 1 segundo várias e várias vezes (na visualização). Sobre o peso do original você não precisa da imagem toda. Se a imagem original será acessada raramente você pode apenas ter o trecho que a marca d'agua sobrepõe original, depois substituir a marca d'agua pela imagem original, que salvou previamente, isso custará processamento e não armazenamento.